# Moving files from an SFTP directory

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, centos, sftp

I have followed this tutorial to configure a Centos 7 server using sftp. The tutorial includes hardening the sftp target directory and user.
The sftpuser is able to sftp files to /var/sftp/uploads

Files are placed in the directory with the following permissions:

```
755 sftpuser:sftpuser
```

A developer has an app which runs as user appuser on the box and wants to move files from that directory to other directories owned by appuser.

The app cannot assume root privileges to move the file from /var/sftp/uploads to /var/uploads/stage, how do I go about doing this without breaking the security I have setup for sftpuser?

```
sshd_config:
Match User sftpuser
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /var/sftp
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```